# Download by appending after some percentage completion

Tags: linux, wget, download

I always use `wget -c` to download a file which enables the download by appending whenever needed from the last position of download.

A file is downloaded `30%`. Then after network occupancy it started appending some junk to the file at the end and reached till `40%`. (Junk added due to the file server's logic to give crap data after `30mins`).

Now, I have got a new url location with some new token available for next `30mins` for the same file. How can I continue downloading the same file but started from `30%` onwards ?

Or is there any application which does that?

ex:

```
$ wget -c http://xyz.com/file.txt?token=1

30% [=============>                                 ]
40% [=================>                             ] (10%junk added)

^C - cancelled

$ wget -c http://xyz.com/file.txt?token=2 --from='30%'

31% [+++++++++++++=>                               ]
```

Note :-  `--from='30%'` is just for example if can be done. there is nothing like that argument exists in `wget`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget -c / --continue` always continues with the given filesize, but you can change that:

Use `truncate` to reduce the file back to the original `30%` size (you have to specify the size in bytes or kbytes). Or you can use `head -c SIZE file > file_30pc`, which does not touch the original file (but then you have to rename it).

And as BlueManCZ suggested, you might want to use `-O output-file` to make sure it is the same file.

**Note:** Using `--start-pos` instead of `-c/--continue` to specify the last good position will **not** work, instead it creates a new file from that position onward, it does not append an existing one (it will even override if you specify `-O`).

Comment: Will it retain the same metadata/mimes of file? I haven't tried though.

Comment: A plain file on Unix has no separate mimetype or metadata (other than permissions/ACLs), so yes, after truncating the file it identical to the one at the 30% mark (given you know the size).

Comment: head truncation is awesome. --start-pos works but creates a new file with .n (.1, .2) extension. I guess after proper download I'd have to merge into one file.

Comment: Yes, `--start-pos` does *not* play nice with `--continue` (in fact, it warns you) and just creates a new file. Editing my answer to hilight that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to continue downloading same file from another URL (or renamed file), you must specific name of file in your command.

```
wget -c -O myfilename https://examle.net/file1.txt

[will be stoped in 30%]

wget -c -O myfilename https://another_url.net/file2.txt

[will start on 30% of previous file]
[file1.txt and file2.txt must be same]
```

But I don't know, if it's answer exactly to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can give a try to another awesome Linux tool called aria2 here is what you need to do to resume your download

```
aria2c -c -m 0 -o "myfile.zip" "http://example.com/file.zip"
```

here -c tells to continue the previous download
     -m tells to retry downloads infinite times 
     -o tells the output file

give it a try aria2 is one of the best downloader for Linux